# How can I make my hair look neat and structured?

Tags: personal-care, hair

I want to improve my hair structure. Whenever I comb my hair, they won't stay structured.
It will deviate on its own way. When I shampoo my hair, it looks ok.

Comment: Hi jadeja prem, Welcome to Lifehacks. Are you happy with the cut?

Comment: Don't know whatever the style I am choosing, my hair would have some structure only for a few days after my cut, afterwards, it becomes messy. how can I make it look structured when I have long hair

Comment: Either have it as a pony tail, or style it to suit your hair instead of fighting it. That would be individual, not a clone style, meaning you would look like you, not like someone else.

Comment: thank u bro, i dont have such thick hair so i could make a pony tail.

Comment: Can you add a comparison picture which will help us understand what "neat and structured" means? @jadejaprem

Comment: Dandruff could be the problem. Have you tried blow dryer or gel?

Comment: No, I am afraid of getting more dandruff and lose my hair if I use gel or blow dryer.

Answer (score 1):

For 10 years I've relied on castile soap, natural conditioner occasionally, and a daily application of hair pomade after showering.

Personally I prefer Dr. Bronner's for my [soap](https://shop.drbronner.com/pure-castile-liquid-soap#scent=Peppermint) and [conditioner](https://shop.drbronner.com/organic-hair-rinse), and Badger for my [pomade](https://www.badgerbalm.com/p-527-hair-pomade.aspx).

The washing/conditioning of hair is self-explanatory.

For pomade, take an amount approximately equivalent to half the size of the final digit on your pinky finger, spread it between your fingers, and apply it throughout your hair starting with the ends.
Then you can comb your hair into the style you prefer. If your hair isn't rigid enough, repeat with slightly more pomade.

Remember, you can always add more pomade, but it's often time-intensive to shower again after applying too much!

Comment: And that advice from a poster that covers his hair in the profile picture ;-) Just kidding welcome to Lifehacks SE! If you haven’t had the time, I recommend you take the [tour] and browse through the [help] to learn more about how the site works.

Answer (score 0):

You can comb your hair in the bathroom after shampooing it and applying balm/mask/conditioner. Comb with WET BRUSH while having any conditioning solution on it rinse and don't comb afterwards. Apply on damp hair any conditioning spray. Is your hair colored?

Comment: no, my hair is not coloured.

Comment: What I wrote above works for me, my hair also not colored. And when I want to restyle it I spray again with any heavy in conditioning spray and it stays.

Answer (score 0):

This will be difficult to pinpoint a good solution without more details.

- Is your hair frizzy? Then it is possible that your hair is just really dry and doing deep conditioning once x week will help immensely.
- Is your hair not frizzy but just kind of like a "halo" and you want it to lay better? Try getting a plastic spray bottle and filling it 50% water and 50% conditioner. Spray when going out and flatten hair with hands.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have problems with the own structure of your hair, I wont tell you  to use gel, it won´t work and it's not very nice to have rock hard hair!

Buy some aloe vera shampoo it's the best softening shampoo plus if you start combing, it wont take you more than 5 seconds if your hair is still a bit wet, to get it looking very nice + the shampoo also gives avery nice shine.
The only problem with aloe shampoo's is: "Where do you find them?"
The answer isn't very easy, the shampoo isn't easy to find, but the price will be very similar to other shampoos, so don't worry about that.
If you are using gel, take in min that it isn't good for the hair, it will make your hair drop sooner than later and it sometimes doesn't look very good plus later your hair is kind of stiff and you have to shower even if you had it not long ago the same day.
So do get some day some aloe vera shampoo and some hair conditioner also of aloe vera, the combination will leave very soft hair, a celestial shine, and finally, lots of happiness for having the best hair in between quite a lot of people.

Comment: All that text (and I have taken some out already) to just say that one plant material in shampoo can do the job.

Comment: This simply repeats content from the existing answers.